# Importing a CSV with multisegmented lines into QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, import

I have successfully imported points in QGIS using csv import previously, but now I have a file that has what I am assuming are multisegmented lines that I need to break into discrete lat/lon fields.  This is what one of the records looks like:

LINESTRING(-122.17646 37.70439, -122.17637 37.70429, -122.17634 37.70419, -122.17594 37.70359)

I am assuming this is a line made up of 4 points creating three segments.  I can break these up into 8 columns and label with unique labels, or put into 4 records with same id for each segment of the line, or ....?

What can I do?

Comment: Are all your linestring the same length or not? What is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Where did this LINESTRING come from?